# __block weak is crashing when success block is initiated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am having a hard time understanding this:

```
__block __weak MyCell *weakSelf = self;
[NetworkManager profileImageForUser:id success ^(UIImage *image, NSString *userId){
       weakSelf.leftImageView.image = image;
}];
```

The issue is that when MyCell is deallocated and then the success block is initiated, then it crashes saying unrecognized selector sent to instance. How do I deal with this?

Comment: You only need to make a weak reference to `self` to avoid a retain cycle.  That doesn't seem to be what is going on here.  If this block were an iVar inside `self` then you would need to do this.  In fact, I would think that retaining `self` is the behavior you want in this situation since you don't want it to be deallocated until at least the end of the block.

Comment: What is the unrecognized selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this crash is happening is that weakSelf is not being retained by the block, which is probably executed asynchronously after the deallocation of the object.

Why are you using __block here? This is the cause of your problem.

__block is only necessary when you are going to MODIFY the object in question from inside the block. __block also prevents the behaviour of the block retaining the object. Since you are not changing the VALUE of weakSelf (only it's properties), you should not use __block so that the block will retain the object and thus have it in memory when it is required, preventing this crash.

Comment: `__block` does *not* prevent retaining the object under ARC.  Please be careful.

Comment: @borrrden You're correct (I don't use ARC in practice :/).<br/> What I was referring to though is this little tidbit from [Apple's block documentation(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html)<br/> _Note: In a garbage-collected environment, if you apply both __weak and __block modifiers to a variable, then the block will not ensure that it is kept alive._

Answer (score 0):

How do you deal with this? You could just check the value of `weakSelf` to make sure it's not `nil` before you use it (because you've effectively said that you didn't want it to be retained, but it will be set to `nil` if the object was released):

```
__weak MyCell *weakSelf = self;
[NetworkManager profileImageForUser:id success ^(UIImage *image, NSString *userId){
       if (weakSelf)
           weakSelf.leftImageView.image = image;
}];
```

Or just abandon the use of `weakSelf` and use `self` (which will retain it for you until the block completes):

```
[NetworkManager profileImageForUser:id success ^(UIImage *image, NSString *userId){
       self.leftImageView.image = image;
}];
```

Either way, don't use `__block` since you're not changing the object itself, just its properties.